# Powershell extraction memory consuming

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, extract, ram

I have worked on a little project which is to extract some information out of a file server. To perform that projet I have created a script that outputs all the information in a .csv file. The problem is that Powershell eats up all my computer's RAM during the process because there is like hundreds Gb of data to parse.

Hereunder is my script.

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'Complete_Path' | select FullName, @{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner}}, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime, PSIsContainer | sort FullName
$output = @()

$folder | foreach {

$type =

if ($_.PSIsContainer -eq "True") {


    Write-Output "Folder"

        }
else {


    Write-Output "File"

}


$size =

if ($_.PSIsContainer -eq "True") {

   Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | measure -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -ExpandProperty Sum


        }
else {


    Get-Item $_.FullName | measure -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -ExpandProperty Sum

}


$hash = @{


FullName = $_.FullName
Owner = $_.Owner
CreationTime = $_.CreationTime
LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
LastAccessTime = $_.LastAccessTime
Type = $type
'Size in MB' = [math]::Round($($size/1Mb),2)

}

$output += New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
}

$output | select FullName, Owner, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime, Type, 'Size in MB' | Export-Csv C:\myDOCS.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Have you guys any idea how can I get the job done faster and less ram consuming? It can take days to get the extraction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [1] using `+=` on an array **_copies to a new, one-item-larger array, adds the new item, and then deletes the old array_**. this will require that you have TWO copies of the array in RAM when doing an add. so ... don't do that. [*grin*] use a collection type that has an `.Add()` method like `generic.list` does.  ///// next item in next comment ...

Comment: [continued from previous comment ...] ///// [2] to save RAM, use a pipeline so that only the current working items are in RAM. the trade off here is slower speed for less RAM. ///// [3] if that doesn't suit you, you move your export line into the loop and immediately export each item instead of saving it all in RAM. this, too, will slow things down a great deal, but will use less RAM overall.

Comment: Thank you for all this information @Lee_Dailey. However I am a bit lost in all this. Where should I apply these changes?

Comment: i see that others have already answered you in excellent detail, so i will just suggest that you go with their code  - an hopeflly recall the _why_ of what i was talking about. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

- Replace your Powershell array `$output=@()` with A .Net PSObject list `$output =  [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new()` and use the **.Add** method of that object to add your items.

  For small list, you won't notice but using Powershell array and **+=** operator is a big performance sink. Each time you do +=, array is recreated entirely with one more item.
- Include Length in your initial Get-ChildItem statement. Later on, you can measure the sum without going through Get-ChildItem again all the time
- Pipeline play nice on memory but slower overall. I tend to prefer not using the pipeline when performance become an issue.

Something like that should already be significantly faster

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Downloads" | select FullName, @{Name = "Owner"; Expression = { (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner } }, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime, PSIsContainer, Length | sort FullName
$output = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new()

foreach ($Item in $folder) {
    if ($Item.PSIsContainer) {
        $Type = 'Folder'
        $size = $folder.Where( { $_.FullName -like $item.FullName }).FullName | measure -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -ExpandProperty Sum
    }
    else {
        $Type = 'File'
        $size = $Item.Length
    }
    $size = [math]::Round($($size / 1Mb), 2)

    $hash = @{
        FullName       = $Item.FullName
        Owner          = $Item.Owner
        CreationTime   = $Item.CreationTime
        LastWriteTime  = $Item.LastWriteTime
        LastAccessTime = $Item.LastAccessTime
        Type           = $Type
        'Size in MB'   = $size
    }
    [void]($output.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $hash)))
}


$output | select FullName, Owner, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime, Type, 'Size in MB' | Export-Csv C:\myDOCS.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

- You could still improve on the size calculation so the deepest of folders size is calculated first, then parent folder can grab the value and sum up the children folder instead of recalculating the files
- Another thought would be to not do the Get-ACl immediately (I suspect this one is slow to perform ) and get your items, do the rest, then parallelize the Get-ACL so you can get the values on a number of parallel threads and add the the value as you get it to your list.

Think about testing your code on smaller batches and use the Measure-Command to determine where are the slowest operation in your code.

I recommend you taking a look at some more advanced topic on the subject.
Here's a good article to get your started : [Slow Code: Top 5 ways to make your Powershell scripts run faster](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/07/12/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster/)

Comment: Ultimately, if you have some knowledge with .Net, building a small DLL to do very intensive stuff like that can be very beneficial. Using ```Add-Type```, you can import the dll into Powershell and still do everything you want from Powershell except the core loop. But if not, there's steps you can take to make your pure powershell code a lot faster and less memory intensive, as per my answer.

Comment: [Appending to arrays](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/07/12/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster/): `$output.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $hash))` is the same wrong approach as `$output += New-Object PSObject -Property $hash`. Check [this @js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56281710/3439404) for proper method.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a shot first thing tomorrow. I will let you all know.

Comment: @JosefZ Appending to array, yes. I am using a .net collection (Article I referenced  mention ArrayList but ArrayList is deprecated, hence my choice of System.collections.Generic.list as collection type.

Comment: Hey guys! I have just had the opportunity to give your scripts a test. I have fed all these with a 56.5 Gb directory and measured the execution runtime to see how long it took to get the final csv file. So, my initial script took 00:02:06, js2010 00:01:57 and SagePourpre 00:02:32. I will definitely go with piping from now on! Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Is this better with the whole thing in one pipeline?

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
select FullName, @{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner}},
CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime, PSIsContainer | sort FullName |

foreach {

  $type =
  if ($_.PSIsContainer -eq "True") {
      Write-Output "Folder"
  }
  else {
      Write-Output "File"
  }

  $size =
  if ($_.PSIsContainer -eq "True") {
     Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | 
       measure -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
       select -ExpandProperty Sum
  }
  else {
      Get-Item $_.FullName | 
        measure -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        select -ExpandProperty Sum
  }

  $hash = @{
    FullName = $_.FullName
    Owner = $_.Owner
    CreationTime = $_.CreationTime
    LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
    LastAccessTime = $_.LastAccessTime
    Type = $type
    'Size in MB' = [math]::Round($($size/1Mb),2)
  }

  New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
} | select FullName, Owner, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime,
Type, 'Size in MB' | 
Export-Csv myDOCS.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: You needn't compute an auxiliary `$hash` object. Just return `[PSCustomObject]@{ … }`.